Derive a matrix derivative involved Hadamard product
Let both $y,x$ be some given vectors, and $A$ be some given matrix. Define $f(M)= \| y- AMx\|_2^2$. Then it is well known that
$$\frac{d}{d M}f(M) = 2A^T (AMx-y)x^T.$$
However, if seems not very simple for me to get $\frac{d}{d M}f(M \odot M)$, even with $\partial (X \odot Y) = \partial X \odot Y + X \odot \partial Y$.
I do not see how (or whether at all) chain rule works here. Could you pls help me a bit in this? Thanks!!

Try working with components instead of vectors or matrices. Things get much simpler.

$
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\bb#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\BLR#1{\bb{\LR{#1}}}
\def\RLR#1{\rr{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Give the Hadamard product its own variable name
$$\eqalign{
P &= M\h M &\qiq \rr{dP=2M\h M} \\
\bb{w} &\bb{= \LR{APx-y}} \\
}$$
Apply the function to $P$ and rewrite the well-known gradient in differential form
$$\eqalign{
F &= f(P) \\
\grad FP &= 2A^Twx^T \qiq dF=\LR{2A^Twx^T}:\rr{dP} \\
}$$
Finally, change the independent variable from $P\to M$
and rearrange it into a gradient
$$\eqalign{
dF &= \LR{2A^Twx^T}:\RLR{2M\h dM} \\
 &= \lR{2M\h\LR{2A^T\bb{w}\,x^T}}:dM \\
 &= \lR{4M\h\LR{A^T\BLR{APx-y}x^T}}:dM \\
\grad FM
 &= \;4M\h\lR{A^T\LR{APx-y}x^T} \\
\\
}$$

In the derivation above, I use a colon to denote the Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
\LR{C\h A}:B &= C:\LR{A\h B} \\
}$$

I use the differential to calculate derivatives involving multi-dimensional quantities, when I don't want to explicitly use coordinates.
In this case, for a variation $\delta M$ in $M$,
\begin{align*}
[df]\delta M &= \frac{d}{dt}f(M + t\delta M)\Big\vert_{t\to 0}\\
&= (- A\delta Mx)^T(y-AMx) + (y- AMx)^T(-A\delta Mx)\\
&= 2(AMx-y)^TA\delta Mx
\end{align*}
which I cannot fully reconcile with your "well known" formula. But in any case, from here we can use the chain rule: since $d(M\odot M)\delta M = M \odot \delta M  + \delta M \odot M = 2M\odot \delta M$,
$$d[f(M\odot M)]\delta M = 2[A(M\odot M)x-y]^TA(2M \odot \delta M)x.$$
